# Degrees of freedom of t-test in multiple regression .

Tags: statistics, regression

Formula of t-test in  regression is,
$ t=\frac{\hat{\beta}-\beta}{se (\hat{\beta})} $
and the degrees of freedom of t-test is (n-k) because we estimate $\hat{\sigma}^2$ from RSS and the RSS has (n-k) degrees of freedom (the model has k number of parameters including intercept term.).But what i am not understand, is that we also estimate$\hat{\beta}$ from  $$\hat{\beta}=\frac{\sum (x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}{\sum (x_i-\bar{x})^2} $$ Here we lost 1 degrees of freedom for estimating $\bar{y}$.
That tells us that we lost k degrees of freedom for calculating residuals and 1 for estimating $\hat{\beta}$. So the degrees of freedom should be  n-k-1 instead of (n-k).What i am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Note that for multiple regression model, where $k\ge 3$, the general formula for the coefficients is
$$
\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'y, 
$$
such that only for the $y=\beta_0 +\beta_1x+\epsilon$ case you get for $\hat{\beta}_1=\frac{\sum(x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})}{\sum(x_i - \bar{x})^2}$, otherwise $\beta_1$, and each one of the other coefficients will differ according to $k$. As such, intuitively, the model loses $1$ df for every estimated coefficient. So, in particular, for the $\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n-k}\sum(y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2  $ estimator, you are using $\hat{\mathrm{\beta}} = (\hat{\beta}_1, ..., \hat{\beta}_k )$, where $\mathrm{dim(\hat{\beta})}=k\times 1$, hence the total number of df for the $t$-test is $n-k$.

Comment: So when we estimate $\hat{\sigma}^2$ ,we are actually using $\hat{\beta}$ to calculate it ,so we loss k number of degrees of freedom .That"s why we do not need to reduce any degrees of freedom for $\hat{\beta}$. @ A.E

Comment: Yes, it is right. Another way to see it is by the rank of the $H$ (hat) matrix, which equals $k$, so the rank of the orthogonal projection $I-H$ is $n-k$ (the "annihilator": $e = (I-H)y$). But basically, it means the same.